# Horizontal scroll on WordPress theme only on firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

my WordPress theme loads properly on all browsers except firefox - where I have a horizontal scroll on all my pages.

In other words, I should only be able to scroll up and down, but on firefox I can scroll left and right a little bit too.

E.g. https://b2english.com/test/

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Brian

Comment: Inspect the html and look at what element sticks out to the side?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on thrv_wrapper thrv-page-section

```
margin-left: -20px !important;
margin-right: -20px !important;
```

Took ten seconds to find it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
[data-css="tve-u-15efc72e013"] {
    padding: 44px 0px 40px !important;
    margin-top: -10px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Due to some... uh... decisions Mozilla made when designing Firefox, pages with negative margins (such as `margin-left: -20px;`) show up kinda funky (aka. horizontal scrolling).

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: it's not what mozilla documentation says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom

Comment: Mozilla isn't going to admit it.

Comment: It seem you are expressing an opinion more than an answer. To me your answer is of very low quality because of that.

Comment: Looks like the commentary is for the need of the answer, not the answer itself. Let's try to be nicer with new users who are making a decent attempt to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling issue is not limited to Firefox, Chrome shows it too:

[image]

**Ashley's answer is spot on.** The odd usage of negative margins is generating the issue. You might also want to strip all the excessive margins, starting from body, and add a solid padding to a single parent container.

[image]

Using a yellow background on an absolutely positioned element to colour the first section...instead of simply colouring the first section directly, is also not recommended.

This element provides nothing:

```
<div class="tve-page-section-out" data-css="tve-u-15e3fa999e0"></div>
```

Simply add your rule:

```
background-color: rgb(245, 215, 110);
```

to the real parent:

```
<div class="thrv_wrapper thrv-page-section" style="" data-css="tve-u-15efc72e013">
```

like this:

```
.thrv-page-section { background-color: rgb(245, 215, 110); }
```